# report server in oracle forms 10g. how can add more report servers Like One Report Server with the name of H.R, 2nd Sales and 3rd Finance

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

Hi everyone I am working on oracle forms 10g I Install forms 10g and application server 10g. I have a default report server. Respected all I want add more report server.
**Like I want one Report Server for H.R and one for Sales and for Finance.**

I see somewhere where someone did like this. how can I make this with 3 different names how can I install that I tried to read many notes and article but didn't get it please help me regarding this. my best regards